# Window Point Reset After Update

Tags: buffers, window, frames, motion, window-point

I have a buffer which is updated periodically using `run-at-time`, and in order to maintain the point in each window I use `set-window-point`, but I find that in sometimes when something is interrupted and an update happens in between, the window point is not reset.  For example, take:

```lisp
(defun example ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buf (get-buffer-create "*Example*"))
         (w-points (mapcar (lambda (win)
                             `(,win . ,(window-point win)))
                           (get-buffer-window-list buf))))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (let ((buf-point (point)))
        (erase-buffer)
        (insert "line1\nline2\nline3\nline4\nline5")
        (goto-char buf-point)
        (mapc (lambda (wp) (set-window-point (car wp) (cdr wp))) w-points)))
    (message "Ran update")))

(setq example-timer (run-at-time t 5 #'example))
```

Now with a configuration of two windows, switch to the example buffer in one of them, and move down a few lines.  Switch to the other window, you should see the window point stay the same after every update.

If you then invoke `M-x` (though any kind of minibuffer interaction will suffice), wait for an update to occur, and then cancel the invocation using `C-g`, then you should see the point in the window displaying the example buffer go back to the start of the window.
Edit: I've created a video here:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17688577/210167335-f7a4d50f-dbaf-4ffc-b1e0-38c5612ed2e3.mp4

What can I do to make this second case not happen so that the window point stays the same regardless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `(setq read-minibuffer-restore-windows nil)` gives the desired behaviour.  From the documentation of `read-minibuffer-restore-windows`:

```
Non-nil means restore window configurations on exit from minibuffer.
```

Which includes window points, so changes to the window configuration as a result of a timer run whilst the minibuffer is active are reverted.  Note as long as you don't remove `minibuffer-restore-window` from `minibuffer-exit-hook` the `*Completions*` window will still be closed:

```
However, if minibuffer-restore-windows is present
in minibuffer-exit-hook, exiting the minibuffer will remove the window
showing the *Completions* buffer, if any.
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying your example with `emacs -Q` (no init file), but after changing `(get-buffer-window-list buf)` to `(get-buffer-window-list buf nil t)`, seems to work for me.

IOW, change optional arg `ALL-FRAMES` to `t`.  Maybe you were testing without being in the frame where you had the `*Example*` windows? By default, `get-buffer-window-list` uses only the windows of the selected frame. Here's what the doc says:

> **`ALL-FRAMES`** `nil` or omitted means consider all windows on the
> selected frame, plus the minibuffer window if specified by the
> `MINIBUF` argument.  If the minibuffer counts, consider all windows
> on all frames that share that minibuffer too.  The following
> non-`nil` values of `ALL-FRAMES` have special meanings:
>
> - `t` means consider all windows on *all existing frames&.
> - `visible` means consider all windows on all *visible frames* on
>   the current terminal.
> - `0` (the number zero) means consider all windows on all *visible
>   and iconified frames* on the current terminal.
> - A *frame* means consider all windows on that frame only.
>
> Anything else means consider all windows on the *selected frame*
> and no others.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  However, I find I get the same behaviour setting the `ALL-FRAMES` flag to `t` (using emacs -Q), and I'm using only one frame.  I've also created a video (linked in the question) showing the behaviour I'm seeing, hopefully that gives a better idea of what's going on than I can describe (: